# Excel - Subtotal based on multiple columns

Tags: excel

I have an XLS with the following columns: Locations, Dates (dd/mm/yyyy), Amounts ($).
I want to create another sheet in the workbook that will summarize the amounts by location and month so that I can see the total monthly per location, grand total monthly (vertical  monthly total, for all locations), and total annual (horizontal YTD for a location) and grand total annual (for all locations).

Basically, create this report from the main spreadsheet:

Location Jan    Feb...  Dec    Total YTD 
Loc1       $1000  $1000   $1500    $3500 
Loc2       $3000  $1000   $500     $6500 
Loc3       $2000  $1000   $2500    $7500 
========================================
Total:   $6000  $3000...$4500    $17500

Any suggestions on how to achieve this? What functions to look into?

Comment: Do some research on how to use `=SUMIFS()`.  I'm pretty sure that will get you there.

Comment: Sounds like a job for pivot tables: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-PivotTable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576

Comment: I agree with @JohnColeman use pivot tables

Answer (score 0):

Yes, pivot tables seem to do the trick, thanks for the suggestion and the article.
That article and how to group the dates into months (from http://www.techrepublic.com/article/pro-tip-group-an-excel-pivottable-by-dates/) gives me pretty much what I was looking for. Thank you guys!!